# React native building release isn't reflecting changes that debug does (android)

Tags: react-native

I made some styling changes to my react native app. Everything looks good in debug so I tried to run the release variant using 'react-native run-android --variant=release' and none of that changes in debug show up. I made sure I wasn't crazy and removed the background image. The release variant didn't change at all. I then tried generating the signed apk and installing it manually. Same thing.

I can't seem to find anything on google. Has anyone had this problem before or have suggestions on what to try? I've combed through all the config files and everything seems right. I know its hard without being able to look at the code but I can't share it since its for internal company use only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For anyone still struggling with this, updating index.android.bundle usually solves this issue:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Comment: This saved my arse.  Thank you.  I don't understand why this isn't documented.  Even knowing what question to ask when this is necessary is a challenge.

Comment: struggling from 5hrs.
You saved my life

Comment: Thanks! worked liked a charm with a small change. In my case it was `--entry-file index.js`

Answer (score 0):

1 - Perform adb reverse..check below got to platform-tools in cmd
  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools --> adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

2 - Then delete any bundle file if present in assets folder
  react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output
  android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

3 - run --> react-native run-android --variant=release
or react-native run-android